# JSON: key value concatenation in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse json object to get the key and value concatenated to a variable. 
My desired output from the given json is:

```
"/" - 7.84 GiB; "/opt" - 4.86 GiB; "/usr" - 4.80 GiB
```

Using my snippet i can get objects but struggling to get the name and value in desired format. Please assist.

```
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) 
{
 if  ( obj[i].name === 'mountpoints') 
 {
 js_mountpoints = obj[i].value;
 break;
 }
 js_mountpoints = 'NA';
}
```

My JSON input:

```
[{
    "name" : "pe_build",
    "value" : "2016.2.1"
}, 
{
    "name" : "kernel",
    "value" : "Linux"
}, {
    "name" : "blockdevices",
    "value" : "sda,sdb,sr0"
},
{
    "name" : "mountpoints",
    "value" : {
        "\/boot\/efi" : {
            "size_bytes" : 261861376,
            "size" : "249.73 MiB",
            "capacity" : "0%"
        },
        "\/opt" : {
            "size_bytes" : 2086666240,
            "size" : "1.94 GiB",
            "capacity" : "1.64%"
        },
        "\/boot" : {
            "size_bytes" : 258650112,
            "size" : "246.67 MiB",
            "capacity" : "74.28%"
        },
        "\/var" : {
            "size_bytes" : 10475274240,
            "size" : "9.76 GiB",
            "filesystem" : "xfs",
            "capacity" : "4.01%"
        }
    }
    },  {
    "name" : "uptime_seconds",
    "value" : 244181
}, {
"name" : "memoryfree",
"value" : "6.66 GiB"
}, {
"name" : "memoryfree_mb",
"value" : 6816.91796875
}
]
```

Comment: Your for loop will iterate over outer values of Json. You need to another iterate inside data object. Also once you reach desired key, you will need to pull **size** from that object.

Comment: Would be great if you could post valid JSON

Comment: @adeneo,thanks for your reply.  i've updated the JSON ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
finalStr = ''
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  if (obj[key].name === 'mountpoints') { // only get sizes for mountpoints
    var value = obj[key].value;
    Object.keys(value).forEach(function(name) { // add all sizes to string
      finalStr += '"' + name + '" - ' + value[name].size + ';';
    }); //update
  }
}); //update

if (finalStr.length > 0) { // at least one entry was added
  finalStr.slice(0, -1);
}
```